# Paint component drawing not appearing on frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have the following class (panel class), and a main class (Main class), shown below the panel class. The code is suppose to display the text that is inside the `paintComponent` method. Although, the frame opens, showing the title I provided, it does not display the string from `paintComponent`. I wrote the code following a tutorial on Java website, and I don't know why it's not working.

### `panel`

```
package com.learn.java;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class panel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.drawString("From Paint Component Method ", 10, 20);

    }
}
```

### `Main`

```
package com.learn.java;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame Frame = new JFrame("The big Title");
        Frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Frame.setSize(850, 800);
        Frame.setVisible(true);
        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame.add(new panel());
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to know how to use FlowLayout .. remove  Frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); and it will work

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. The code now works, like you said. Wanted to mark you answer as "the answer that solved the problem" but it didnt give me the option. Will look into Flow Layout.

Comment: *"I wrote the code following a tutorial on Java website, and I don't know why it's not working."* BTW - what's the link to this tutorial?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html

Comment: Above is the link to the Tutorial, Andrew Thompson. The tutorial  is much more elaborate than my code: it uses things like swingUtilities, which I don't use. Mine is a striped-down version of it. P.S, will look into the advises you provided in you other comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code has a number of problems, and the solution suggested in comments is sub-optimal.

First, the paint chain in the custom painted component is broken. The overridden method needs to call the super method, but instead calls the 'plural' version. To fix it, change:

```
super.paintComponents(g);
```

To:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

Now onto the stated problem. Getting rid of the `FlowLayout` hides the problem because while flow layout respects the preferred size of components (and does not stretch them) the default layout of a `JFrame` (`BorderLayout`) does stretch components to fill the available space.

The correct approach is to have the custom painted component override the `getPreferredSize()` method. Then it will appear as expected in a flow layout.

Once that is taken care of, remove:

```
Frame.setSize(850, 800);
```

Since it is just a guess.. Then move..

```
Frame.setVisible(true);
```

To the last statement and immediately before it, put..

```
Frame.pack(); // make the GUI the correct size
```

A further tip: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.